# "ORA-00936: missing expression" on DATE

Tags: oracle, db2, ora-00936

at work we're undergoing a migration from DB2 for iSeries SQL to Oracle SQL and are experiencing some pains. I'd still consider myself a beginner with SQL and can't figure out what Oracle SQL doesn't like about this clause.

```
  CASE 
        WHEN YYCOL IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE max ( DATE ( MMCOL || '/' || DDCOL || '/' || YYCOL ) ) 
  END AS COLUMN007
```

When querying with the above clause:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
            ELSE max ( DATE ( MMCOL || '/' || DDCOL || '/' || YYCOL ) ) 
                       ^
```

If possible, is there some easy to digest documentation for moving from DB2 for iSeries SQL to Oracle SQL? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use -

```
CASE 
        WHEN YYCOL IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE max ( TO_DATE ( MMCOL || '/' || DDCOL || '/' || YYCOL, 'MM/DD/YY' ) ) 
  END AS COLUMN007
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Ankit! Now to figure out how to TRUNC the thing so it only shows the date stamp...

Answer (score 0):

"so it only shows the date stamp"  The to_date converts the provided string to oracle internal, binary DATE datatype, which also always includes the time down to the second.  But to "show" a  date, that DATE type has to be converted back to a string of characters.  This is normally done by use of TO_CHAR, providing a DATE and a 'format mask'.  Since you did not provide that, oracle was forced to do it implicitly, and use the effective value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  If want it to only "show" the date, then

```
to_char(to_date(MMCOL||'/'||DDCOL||'/'||yycol,'mm/dd/yy'),'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

I encourage you to go to the official oracle docs and look up the to_date and to_char function.  See also an article I wrote on it, at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

As an aside, please quit using 2-digit years.  20 years ago I and thousands of guys like me were busting our butts to prevent a meltdown on 1-Jan-2000.  And just last week I read an article that systems that had kicked the can down the road with a 'pivot date' were now coming to grief as of 1-Jan-2020.  Please quit repeating the same mistakes we were supposed to have corrected 20 years ago.

Comment: Thank you, Ed! I had tried TO_CHAR, but was using it in the wrong place. Our years are 4 digits; that was a "typo" on my end when I substituted the column names.